# jQuery - criar um elemento jQuery ( criar uma tag ) a partir de uma string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho feito para criar um elemento ( uma tag ) o seguinte código:

```
var b = $('<div>').css('color','red');
```

Desta maneira acima terei uma div com o texto de cor vermelho ok, agora é o seguinte.

Estou recebendo uma ***STRING*** que contém todo o código da tag assim:

```
var a = "<div style=\"text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; padding-bottom: 2px; text-align: center; margin-top: 4px;\">47782</div>";
$(a).css('color','red'); //TENTATIVA DE ALTERAR A COR, MAS NÃO DA ERRO NEM FUNCIONA
```

Porém não esta alterando, eu não posso criar essa tag como no primeiro trecho de código, pois o conteúdo dessa string é recebida de forma dinamica no meu script.

Minha dúvida é se tem como eu via jQuery fazer a modificações ou vou ter que fazer tudo na mão mexendo diretamente na string toda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) para transformar tua string em um objeto do dom, depois tu pode inserir esse objeto na página.

```js
var a = "<div style=\"text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; padding-bottom: 2px; text-align: center; margin-top: 4px;\">47782</div>";
var meuHtml = $.parseHTML(a);
$(meuHtml).css('color','red');
$("body").append(meuHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Obrigado, ficou muito bom desse jeito.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazendo uma bela de uma gambiarra

```js
var a = "<div style=\"text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; padding-bottom: 2px; text-align: center; margin-top: 4px;\">47782</div>";
    
$('body').append(
  $(a).wrap('<div>').css('color','red').parent().html()  
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```